# Unexpected syntax error : "\n" in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code is in my javascript/jquery script, but for some reason Firebug tells me I have a "syntax error: `var fbbirthday = ;\n`".

```
var fbbirthday = <?php echo $fb_day_of_birth; ?>;
var fbbirthmonth = <?php echo $fb_month_of_birth; ?>;
var selectbirthyear = $('#ad_engine_birth_date_year').val();
```

Meanwhile, the browser actually shows the following (because the php variables `$fb_day_of_birth` and `$fb_month_of_birth` are empty when the user isn't logged into facebook).

```
var fbbirthday = ;
var fbbirthmonth = ;
var selectbirthyear = $('#ad_engine_birth_date_year').val();
```

I've spent a while trying to figure out where the `\n` that firebug finds is coming from.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `var fbbirthday = ;` is invalid javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement is illegal as the right hand side of the assignment is missing:

```
var fbbirthmonth = ;
```

This is probably due to `$fb_day_of_birth` that is an empty string. You should check that and use an alternative value like:

```
var fbbirthday = <?php echo is_numeric($fb_day_of_birth) ? $fb_day_of_birth : 0; ?>;
```

Or better use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
var fbbirthday = <?php echo json_encode($fb_day_of_birth); ?>;
```